# Get dictionary with lowest key value from a list of dictionaries

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

From a list of dictionaries I would like to get the dictionary with the lowest value for the `'cost'` key and then remove the other key,value pairs from that dictionary

```
lst = [{'probability': '0.44076116',  'cost': '108.41'} , {'probability': '0.55923884',  'cost': '76.56'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a custom `key` function to the [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) built-in function:

```
>>> min(lst, key=lambda item: float(item['cost']))
{'cost': '76.56', 'probability': '0.55923884'}
```

Or, if you just need a minimum cost value itself, you can find a minimum cost value from the list of cost values:

```
costs = [float(item["cost"]) for item in lst]
print(min(costs))
```

Comment: any pythonic suggestion for the second part where I say: "and then remove the other key,value pairs from that dictionary" ?

Comment: @KristofPal you can just get that minimum `cost` this way: `min(lst, key=lambda item: float(item['cost']))["cost"]`..if I understand this part correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @KristofPal added one more option in case we are still on the same page :)

Answer (score 2):

@alecxe's solution is neat and short, +1 for him.  here's my way to do it:

```
>>> dict_to_keep = dict()
>>> min=1000000
>>> for d in lst:
...     if float(d["cost"]) < min:
...         min = float(d["cost"])
...         dict_to_keep = d
...
>>> print (dict_to_keep)
{'cost': '76.56', 'probability': '0.55923884'}
```